# In travis.ci Rscript seems to be ignoring the .Reviron file

Tags: r, travis-ci, rscript

In travis, I am creating a Renviron file with the following line:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN="http://cran.rstudio.com",DRAT="http://sahilseth.github.io/drat")
```

This adds two repositories CRAN (official R repo) and my personal repo.

This works perfectly on my own computer, but on travis, R seems to ignore the .Rprofile file.

Here is a block from travis output (https://travis-ci.org/sahilseth/flowr/builds/84850698)

```
echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN="http://cran.rstudio.com",DRAT="http://sahilseth.github.io/drat")' > .Rprofile
Rscript -e 'options("repos");print(.libPaths())'
```

Output:

```
$repos
    CRAN 
"@CRAN@" 
[1] "/home/travis/Rlib"             "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Running the same on the PC shows:

```
$repos
                 CRAN
"http://cran.rstudio.com"
                 DRAT
"http://sahilseth.github.io/drat
```

Comment: Bizarre. Looking at it now but can't think of anything right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the line you use to create .Rprofile:

```
echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN="http://cran.rstudio.com", 
                        DRAT="http://sahilseth.github.io/drat"))' > .Rprofile
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something you wrote what he wrote.  What is supposed to be different?

Comment: You're missing exactly one `)`. I have two closing parentheses at the end -- he only has one.

Comment: I really don't know, how did I miss that !! embarrassing

Comment: Yup, I missed that too. Well spotted.  And another successful drat use booked :)